# Minimization Problem: Deriving Dual Problem

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems, subgradient

Consider the following minimization problem $\min\{H(x,z) \equiv h_1(x) + h_2(z): Ax + Bz = c\}$, where $A \in \Bbb{R}^{m \times n}, B \in \Bbb{R}^{m \times p}$ and $c \in \Bbb{R}^{m}$ and $h_1, h_2$ are proper, closed and convex.

To find the dual problem of the optimization problem, one can construct a Lagrangian:

$L(x,z;y) = h_1(x)+h_2(z) + \langle y, Ax + Bz - c \rangle$

The objective function is therefore given by

$q(y) = \min_{x, z} \{h_1(x) + h_2(z) + \langle y, Ax+Bz-c \rangle\}$

Apparently, the last line is the same $\max_{y}h_1^{*}(-A^{T}y)-h_2^{*}(-B^{T}y) - \langle c,y \rangle$

I guess that his is an application of some duality principle but I don't see how it exactly works.

Comment: Your first expression for $q$ seems to have a sign error.

Comment: Are you familiar with the conjugate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our problem is equivalent (with some domain qualification conditions) to

$$\min_{x,z}\max_{y} L(x,z,y) =\max_y \Big\{\min_{x} \{ h_1(x) + \langle y, Ax\rangle \} + \min_z \{h_2(z) + \langle y, Bz\rangle\} -\langle y, c\rangle\Big\}$$

Now use the definition of the convex conjugate to get

$$\min_{x,z}\max_y L(x,z,y) = \max_y \{-h_1^*(-A^* y) -h_2^*(-B^*y) - \langle y,c\rangle\}$$

Comment: I don't quite understand how our problem is equivalent to $\min_{x,z}\max_{y} L(x,z,y)$? Could you please elaborate on that one?

Comment: https://www-cs.stanford.edu/people/davidknowles/lagrangian_duality.pdf    

Don't be discouraged by the "for dummies" in the title, it's a nice intuitive explanation. The basic idea is to replace the indicator function for the constraint by a linear function of the constraint while also maximizing over the new linear variable.

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the expression for $q$ without invoking a duality principle. Notice that
\begin{align}
q(y) &= -\langle c,y\rangle + \left(\min_x h_1(x) - \langle y, Ax \rangle \right) + \left(\min_z h_2(z) - \langle y, Bz\rangle \right) \\
&= -\langle c,y\rangle - \left(\max_x \langle -A^T y, x \rangle - h_1(x) \right) -  \left( \max_z \langle -B^T y, z \rangle - h_2(z) \right) \\
&= -\langle c,y\rangle - h_1^*(-A^T y) - h_2^*(-B^T y).
\end{align}

By the way, as a matter of notational style, I prefer to use $x$ and $y$ for primal variables and $z$ for a dual variable.

Comment: Indeed, this is equivalent to what I wrote with $q(y) = \min_{x,z}L(x,z,y)$, except I believe there are sign errors in $h_1^*$ and $h_2^*$.